# Page is not taking masterpage design

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="The_Saloon.master.cs" Inherits="The_Saloon" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Organic Company Template</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
        <link href="App_Themes/maintheme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 7]><link href="App_Themes/maintheme/css/iehacks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="App_Themes/maintheme/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE 6]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="App_Themes/maintheme/js/ie6pngfix.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, ul, ol, li, div, p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
  </script>
  <![endif]-->
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <div class="rapidxwpr floatholder">
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="left" class="clearingfix">
                <a href="App_Themes/maintheme/index.html">
                    <img id="logo" class="correct-png" src="App_Themes/maintheme/images/logo.png" alt="Home"
                        title="Home" /></a>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="" class="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="gallery">Picture Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="events">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="main_container" class="clearingfix">
                    <div id="mainmiddle" class="floatbox withright">
                        <div class="why-organic">
                            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
                                <p>
                                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                                    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                                    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                                    pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
                                    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et
                                    Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus
                                    error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque
                                    ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt
                                    explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut
                                    fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
                                    Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci
                                    velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam
                                    aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
                                    ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis
                                    autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae
                                    consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" 1914
                                    translation by H. Rackham "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea
                                    of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete
                                    account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of
                                    the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids
                                    pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to
                                    pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor
                                    again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself,
                                    because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and
                                    pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us
                                    ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from
                                    it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure
                                    that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant
                                    pleasure?" Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero
                                    in 45 BC "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis
                                    praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi
                                    sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
                                    mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est
                                    et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio
                                    cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
                                    assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis
                                    debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint
                                    et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus,
                                    ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus
                                    asperiores repellat." 1914 translation by H. Rackham "On the other hand, we denounce
                                    with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by
                                    the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee
                                    the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who
                                    fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through
                                    shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish.
                                    In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents
                                    our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every
                                    pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the
                                    obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated
                                    and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to
                                    this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures,
                                    or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."</p>
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            &copy; The Saloon 2012
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi , ive added my masterpage , maybe i did something wrong with the contentplaceholders , i don't know for sure. But my problem is when i'm making a new web form using the masterpage, the only thing that is shown is the background image and thats it. So i don't know whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a Master Page, the content placeholder is a portion where pages that inherit the master page puts their own content. You shouldn't put content in this section on Master Page.

When you reference this ContentPlaceHolder in a page, the content you assigned in the master page would be overriden.

//Page.aspx

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"></asp:Content>
```

that statement has nothing in between, replacing the content in the master page

To achieve what you want do this

//MasterPage.aspx
Move your text out of the

```
<div>
   My default content to show on every page
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent"> <!-- child pages content goes here -->
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

See that I have moved the text out of the ContentPlaceHolder. Try this, your content won't disappear anymore

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you have place content inside the  `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder` this content is removed on the page that use this master page and have this content id defined.

Think that the content that is inside the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder> ... </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` is the default content when on the next page you have set nothing for this particular one.

So for me I will left with out content this part of your page, at least on the header that you complain that is not getting the style.

For example write the head as:

```
<head>
    <title>Organic Company Template</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        <link href="App_Themes/maintheme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 7]><link href="App_Themes/maintheme/css/iehacks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="App_Themes/maintheme/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE 6]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="App_Themes/maintheme/js/ie6pngfix.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, ul, ol, li, div, p, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
  </script>
  <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Comment: The body content is only the lorum text because otherwise something dont load correctly

Comment: @NicolasPierre Niko double check what I say about the header.

Comment: @NicolasPierre If you are place the second page inside a directory, then is not found as you have set it.

Comment: The webforms are in the same directory

Comment: @NicolasPierre You know, I can not debug your code, I am only assume thinks from experience. Open your source page, and open the web browser debug tools to see why is not find them